# How to create a counter example of a matrix with non orthogonal eigenvector?

Tags: education

I am trying to understand this

[orthogonal eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142645/orthogonal-eigenvectors/1815892#1815892)

$$T =  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

let

$$u =  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

$$v =  \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

They are all linearly independent. $u$ and $v$ are eigen vectors of $T$ right?

I just want to make sure I am correct. So those are samples of eigen vectors that not orthogonal. The catch is the eigen value are the same. Namely 1. How can I create eigen vectors that are not orthogonal and have different eigen value?

I want a counter example of a matrix (doesn't have to be symmetric or diagonal) that have non orthogonal eigen vectors with different eigen value.

Comment: [here's that tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360)

Comment: As long as you take diagonalizable symmetrical matrices, the eigenvectors will be orthogonal.

Comment: Long story short: something went "wrong" with your second example because you repeated an eigenvalue. If you want non-orthogonal eigenvectors, you will need a non-symmetric (diagonalizable) matrix.

Comment: Ah what do you mean by diagonlizable matrix? I thought all matrix are diagonalizeable. Just use normal algorithm we use to solve linear equation. Hmmm?

Comment: @Maik Pickl, you are right, but agree with me that identity matrix is so special...

Comment: @JeanMarie I deleted my comment since the question has changed. But this always happens when you have repeated eigenvalues. You can choose a basis of the eigenspace which does not have to be orthogonal.

Comment: I think we can diagonalize any matrix using reduced row echilon form or something like that

Comment: @Maik Pickl You are right. Thank you.

Comment: @JimThio No. The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable. It has the eigenvalue $1$ with algebraic multiplicity $2$ but geometric multiplicity only $1$.

Answer (score 2):

For a non-symmetric matrix take:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 \\ 2& 2 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Then $(1,2)^T$ is a eigenvector to eigenvalue $3$ and $(1,-1)^T$ is a eigenvector to eigenvalue $0$ but they are not orthogonal.

Comment: The eigenvalue of $(1,2)^t$ is $3$, not $2$

Comment: @AmirSagiv Thanks, corrected!